# Ruby localization: i18n, g18n, gettext, padrino... - what's the difference?

Tags: ruby, localization, internationalization, sinatra, padrino

Being somewhat new to Ruby I'm exploring existing libraries to do what I'd normally do in other scripting languages, and I'm a bit stumped by the localization libraries that might be available for something built on top of Sinatra/Sequel (Rails/AR being a bit too opinionated to my taste).

Now, I ran into a couple (i18n, r18n, GetText) though [this wiki page](http://ruby-i18n.org/wiki), and there apparently is an extra library used in Padrino (based on the i18n thing from Rails?); and apparently plenty more.

Except for the obvious (i.e. GetText mo/po style vs yml files), I'm somewhat confused as to how these options might be different. The wiki doesn't point to much in that respect except saying the that they exist; not how they're different.

Adding to this confusion is the fact that essentially every piece of documentation seems to cover a single one of them (and typically in a RoR context). Moreover, these options don't look entirely incompatible with one another on closer inspection -- in the sense that, if I understood this properly, they can understand each other's files to a large extent.

Might anyone here be able to give a quick and to the point explanation/overview of these libraries, and outline the difference between the them? Some pointers on performance would also be welcome, if you're aware of any (besides the ones from the fast_gettext docs, which made little sense considering my lack of understanding the difference between these options).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I can see how this situation is confusing without knowing some of the history of i18n/l10n libraries in Ruby. I should probably write a few words up on that, but for now I'll try to give an overview from my perspective:

[Gettext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_gettext) is obviously the oldest player in this game and it inherits both strengths and weaknesses from its ancestry which is being invented for a C dominated world. It has most features one needs, comes with some tools support that others lack (like desktop po file editors) and is widely accepted in the so called enterprise world.

Gettext as such defines an [API](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#Interface-to-gettext) and there are basically two libraries that implement it in the Ruby world, the traditional [Ruby Gettext](http://www.yotabanana.com/hiki/ruby-gettext.html) packages by [Masao Mutoh](https://github.com/mutoh) and the [fast_gettext](https://github.com/grosser/fast_gettext) gem by [Michael Grosser](https://github.com/grosser).

Ruby Gettext is quite powerful and ships a lot of features that you may or may not need. The fast_gettext gem on the other hand focusses on raw speed and is implemented as a shiny, modern code-style Ruby library that is easily hackable and the author is a very smart and supportive person. Out of the two I'd personally strongly recommend fast_gettext.

The [I18n gem](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n) is the result of the joint effort of various Ruby i18n/l10n solutions that existed a few years ago and that all strived to supersede Gettext for various reasons at that point of time. The resulting I18n API is basically covering the requirements and usecases of all the i18n/l10n solutions involved at that time, including the API of Gettext. So, today's Ruby I18n API is a superset of Gettext's API from the early 90s.

Today the I18n gem is the official solution that is [shipped with Ruby on Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html), but it is also the probably [most popular](http://rubygems.org/gems/i18n/stats) one in the Ruby world in general.

The I18n gem also makes it [very easy to extend](http://vimeo.com/12665914) the featureset and add things like caching, other storage mechanisms (like Gettext po files, database tables, key-value stores; storage defaults to plain Ruby files and YAML) etc. and it ships with a [number of modules](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/tree/master/lib/i18n/backend) for that (but external or custom modules can easily be crafted, tested and integrated).

There are translation files for [70+ languages](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/tree/master/rails/locale) (locales) for strings used by Ruby on Rails (which are useful in other projects, too) maintained by the community.

I can not tell much about [R18n](http://ri18n.berlios.de/) except that it was invented right after I18n hit its first release and as far as I remember it originated from the Merb community. It seems to be rather strong in the Russian Ruby world, but I might be wrong with all these assertions.

So, unless you have a very good reason to pick any other solution I'd strongly recommend using I18n.

Then on the other hand that means nothing because [I've been leading this project](http://svenfuchs.com/2008/7/18/finally-ruby-on-rails-gets-internationalized) more or less since it was invented.

I hope this helps.

[EDIT] added links to various references

Comment: You guys are so great to have stopped by and answered in here. Thank you so much. :-)

Comment: This is wiki material Sven :)

Comment: @svenfuchs, plan to implement your gem for all my Rails applications.  Your video added the missing piece.  For now we are going to use po files since it will be the easiest way to collaborate using several people for each website.  Great information on the video and this post.

Answer (score 5):

I18n is a main stream.

R18n is a alternative with some extra features (model translations, syntax sugar) and some difference in ideology and architecture (flex extensibility by powerful filters).

G18n need to add model transtions to I18n.

Padrino is not a i18n library, it is just Sinatra framework with build-in I18n.

Gettext is IMHO old conception with very ugly format and problem with pluralization. Anyway, it isn’t popular in Ruby community.

Comment: You guys are so great to have stopped by and answered in here. Thank you so much. :-)

Answer (score 5):

First:
as svenfuchs wrote, `I18n` is a framework that provides modules for many translation and internationalisation approaches.
'gettext' is just one of many modules.

So there is really no question to use `I18n`.

The default setup of a Rails application is to use `I18n` with the YAML backend and I understand part of your question to compare that backend with other ones.

---

IMHO there are two major differences between the `gettext` and `YAML` based approaches:

- life cycle support
- hierarchy

**gettext**

One idea of `gettext` is, that translating an app is not a singular event but a life cycle process.
It is build to support this live cycle.

`gettext` is designed to use plain english as the keys for the translations. So the idea is to write the app in english and *mark* all text that is to be translated, typically by wrapping it with `_()`.
As a result, the app source code is easily readable in english.

Then a programm scans all source code and extracts the textes to be translated and builds a *repository* (the `.pot` file) of these textes.

In the next step, and here comes the *live cycle*, the repository is **merged** with existing translations (*.po* files, one for each target language) and new or changed items are marked.

Mature editors support the translators by focusing on the new and changed items. Additionally project specific dictionaries can support partial automatic translations.

`gettext` is *flat*, meaning that each key phrase is translates exactly once in the translation files. There is no hierarchy. But there is context. In the translation files, all the source code positions of a key phrase are listed. An editor with access to the source code can display the source along with the translation (and some do).

Finally, `.po` files are translated to machine readable fast access forms (can be *.mo*, the classic standard, or a database or json or …)

**YAML**

YAML an the other hand is hierarchical so it’s easy to have variations of translations in different contexts.
I18n uses this structure to support `scopes` and uses the current file path as scope when using keys starting with a dot.
There is no information, where a key is used in the project (well unless auto scoped, but the key may be used in other places explicitly).
There is no information, whether there are any changes.
Unless your IDE supports you, the developer has to find the right place to put a key in the YAML and searching the usage can be cumbersome.
A lot more is said in the other answers.

**I18n**

I intentionally said *YAML* and not *I18n*, because *I18n* is a framework for internationalization (not only translation), and *YAML* is only one possible backend.
Plural support in I18n differs from plural support of vanilla gettext. I don’t have experience how they cooperate.

**Examples**

*gettext* with positional parameters:

```
sprintf(
_('Do you really want to delete tour %1$s_%2$s? Only empty tours can be deleted!'),
tag, idx)
```

translations are text files, but PO-Editors provide GUIs:

```
#: js/addDelRow.js:15
msgid "" "Do you really want to delete tour %1$s_%2$s? Only empty tours can be deleted!" 
msgstr "" "Wollen sie die Spalte %1$s_%2$s wirklich löschen? Nur leere Spalten können "
"gelöscht werden."
```

*YAML* with parameters:

Source

```
<%= t('.checked_at', ts: l(checked_at), user: full_name) %>
```

translation
from

```
en:
  hotels:
    form:
      checked_at: „set to checked by %{user} on %{ts}“
```

to

```
de:
  hotels:
    form:
      checked_at: "geprüft gesetzt am %{ts} von %{user}“
```

**Conclusion**

*YAML* is much easier to start with, especially if you have support by an IDE.
Vanilla RAILS has it built in.
The is no *native* language. The first translation can be any language.
With growing projects and multiple laguages, my YAML files tend to repetition (same translation scattered over the hierarchy) and tracing of changes and therefore new translations is cumbersome.

*gettext* needs an extra toolchain and therefore a more difficult setup.
It supports the whole life cycle of continous translation of developing apps.
It is based on english source code.

I usually use the best parts of both, using YAML for internationalisation (number and date format, maybe model names?) and gettext for translation.

Comment: My main problem with gettext() is exactly that: Programs are written in english and then the english strings are translated. This implies the translation of one english string is always the same. This is not how natural languages work though.

Answer (score 2):

Andrey's response as to point me back to the [r18n docs](http://r18n.rubyforge.org/), which basically break it down to a single line:

> R18n uses hierarchical, not English-centric, YAML format for translations by default.

Found this slideshare from Andrey. It's in Russian, but it's making a lot more sense now (slides 7 to 9 in particular clear-cut differences between i18n and r18n):

http://www.slideshare.net/iskin/r18n

Comment: Sure looks like it. Sven's answer is quite rich, but it sadly didn't highlight how i18n and r18n are different, so I figured I'd highlight how I eventually got it. :-)